# Expression must have pointer-to-object type - What do I do?

Tags: visual-studio

This problem keeps on bugging me for a very long time, yet I can't quite understand the problem or how to solve it.

It says that **Expression must have pointer-to-object type** for **i** whenever I am in the **for** loop. Everything else seems to be fine.

```
int number, number0, digit, numberLength = 1, dementor, i;

cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> number;

number0 = number;

while (number0 != 1)
{
    number0 /= 10;
    numberLength++;
}

number0 = number;

for(int i = numberLength; i >= 0; i--)
{
    digit[i] = number0 % 10;
    number0 = number0 / 10;
    cout << digit << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does the error message point to a certain line number?

Comment: line 25, so it would be     digit[i] = number0 % 10;     underscoring **i**